# Extension 'Prettier - Code Formatter' Cannot Format - (Mac v8.0)

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Having a problem with Prettier not being able to format. I have format on save selected, the default format is set to use Prettier. Was working fine yesterday and now it is not formatting on save or when I run the format document command. No settings were changed, I did try uninstalling and reinstalling prettier. Force format document also returns an error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ocsS.png)

[Setting Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sTw6.png)

[Setting Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjEZb.png)

[Version Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmZRl.png)

[Force Format Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udLmu.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prettier VSCode JSON Format Error - SyntaxError: ';' expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664360/prettier-vscode-json-format-error-syntaxerror-expected)

Comment: @JayDev No it does not, I have already found the solution

Comment: I am using v8.1 and still experiencing this in some files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

v8.0 seems to be broken, the solution was to downgrade to v7.1.1.

Found out there were issues here: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/2029

EDIT: v8.1 is out and the issue is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because the prettier setting `Prettier:enable` was not turned on after the extension installed (finally found this after some time wondering why...).

To check go to File->preferences->settings and then type `prettier` and scroll down until you see `Prettier:enable` and make sure it is checked.

(In case you wonder, I figured this out when I look at the output of the prettier console)

[image: Prettier Setting]